# Z value always 1 or -1 when using `glm::perspective`

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I'm trying to teach myself the ways for 3D programming with OpenGL, however I am struggling with some things, especially projection matrices.

I defined some vertices for a cube and successfully handed them to my graphics processor. The cube goes from xyz -0.5 to xyz 0.5 respectively, which gets rendered fine.

To move it into my world coordinate system, I am using this model matrix:

```
auto model = glm::mat4(
    glm::vec4(1, 0, 0, 0),
    glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 0),
    glm::vec4(0, 0, 1, 0),
    glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1)
);
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 495.f));
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(100.f, 100.f, 100.f));
```

This successfully moves my cube to `(-50, -50, 445) -> (50, 50, 545)` so its now centered in the 200x200x1000 world coordinates I defined for myself.

My camera / view matrix is

```
auto view = glm::lookAt(
    glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 5.f),
    glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 0.f),
    glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f)
);
```

which moves the cube slightly closer, changing the z coordinate to 440 and 540 respectively. I don't understand why this is happening but I *guess* it has something to do with glm expecting a right hand coordinate system while I am working with a left handed one? While this is not why I am posting this question, I would be happy if someone would clear it up for me.

Now to my actual problem: I am trying to make use of `glm::perspective`. I call it like this:

```
auto perspective = glm::perspective(glm::radians(55.f), 1.f, 0.f, 1000.f);
```

If I'm not mistaken, at a z value of 440 I can expect the clipping area to go from roughly `-229` to `229`, so I would expect that  bottom right cube vertex at `(-50,-50)` is visible. I calculated this by drawing the frustum in 2D, when I noticed that I *should* be able to calculate the height of any distance to the camera using `tan(alpha / 2) * distToCamera = maxVisibleCoordinate` (working with a 1:1 aspect ratio). Is this a correct assumption? Here is my terrible drawing, maybe you can tell that I have a wrong understanding of something with it:

[image: I hope you can see what I was trying to do]

In the final step I am trying to get all this together in my vertex shader using

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z, 1.0);
```

which yields a perfectly reasonable result for the x and y value but the z value is always `-1` which is, as far as I know, just right for not being displayed.

For my front-bottom-left vertex of the cube `(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)` the result is `(-96.04, -96.04, -440, -440)`, normalized to `(-0.218, -0.218, -1)`.

For my back-top-right vertex of the cube `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` the result is `(96.04, 96.04, -550, -550)`, normalized to `(0.218, 0.218, -1)`.

What am I getting wrong, that my z value is lost and just set to -1 instead? When playing around with the camera position, the best I can get is getting it to 1, which also results in an empty window and is definitely not what I would expect.

Comment: `znear` cannot be zero. Try a small value, for example, 0.1f

Comment: @Amadeus Attempts to answer the question should be posted as an answer. Comments are for asking for clarification about the problem.

Comment: Man, this took me six hours until I finally came here to post this question.
@Amadeus please post this as an answer so I can accept it since its working now. Also, without someone telling me, how could I have known this? Did I just not read the right documentation?

Comment: @Xirema As the post was very big, I was unsure if that was the real problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A projection matrix is like this:

[image]

In the picture, f is for zfar and n is for znear.

As you can see, if you put `znear = 0`, the term at the 4th column become zero, which is incorrect. Also, `-(f+n)/(f-n) = -1`, which is incorrect too.

So, the conclusion is, `znear` cannot be zero. It is usually a small value, for example, 0.1

Comment: The image was taken from here: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_matrix.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and the reference! I will definitely make use of it

Answer (score 3):

Since Amadeus already answered the question correctly, I'm going to just use this space to add some clarifying information about why it's correct.

We can refer back to the diagram you provided to explain what the problem is: You have two planes, the near plane and the far plane, representing the range at which you may view objects. What the Perspective Matrix does is it takes everything in between those two planes, within the Frustrum that you've defined (mathematically a cone, but our monitors are rectangular, so...) and maps them onto the flat Near-plane to create the final image. In a sense, you can think of the Near Plane as representing the monitor.

So given this context, if you were to set the Near Plane's distance to 0, meaning it was identical to the camera, what would happen? Well, in a cone it would set the plane to a single point, and in a frustrum, it's the same. You cannot view objects drawn onto a single point. You need a surface with actual surface area to draw onto.

That is why it is inappropriate to set the near value to 0. It would turn the drawing surface into a single point, and you cannot mathematically render any objects on a single point. Hence why the essential mathematical formulas backing the matrix will break down and result in bad outcomes if you try to do so anyways.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! Its nice having some kind of visual representation of the issue. Just to check if I got you right: To fix my sketch, I would have to draw the vertex of alpha on top of the near plane (or slightly left from it if I set it to 0.1) and not at the center of my camera?